# chart protect selection in excel

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I have created a chart in excel and set protect selection property true in VBA code but when click on it excel to hang.

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: thats good. multiples files are downloading together. what is the issue ?

Comment: Intent service are good for these types of problems. You can keep track of which item is clicked by putting it in shared preferences or anything persistence.

Comment: yes. many times as you want.

Comment: lets amaze yourself :)

Comment: Broadcast receivers are used to notify that something happened, whenever you broadcast something you provide some data with it. in your case assume you pass "some file.jpg has been download" to you activity or something and then you display it. If this is what you are asking then Yes.

Comment: read this through. https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Comment: No, I can't help you with code and no one will, you need to start yourself. if you face any problem post it here, we are here to help you